# Trying to make the object of a class, whose absolute path is known only

Tags: java

```
        File fi = new File("file:///home/abc/Desktop/test/out/production/test/");

        URL url = fi.toURI().toURL();       
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        URLClassLoader classLoad = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class<?> v = classLoad.loadClass("test.out.production.test.Rout");
```

Absolute Path of the class whose object should be created /home/abc/Desktop/test/out/production/test/Rout  (Rout is the required class)

But it is giving ClassNotFound Exception.

Comment: is the windows or mac?

Comment: Generally speaking you need to know the *class name* of the class you want to load and point the URL Class Loader towards the *root* of the directory tree containing the classes.

Comment: I know the class name which  is Rout

Comment: @Joachim Sauer could you please write the correct syntax of doing this